# Aligning TimeSeriesAggregate with calendar months

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've been trying to get the mean monthly values for a financial index but can't get them to fit exactly with the calendar month using TimeSeriesAggregate.

E.g. be it

```
Data2018AgM = TimeSeriesAggregate[FinancialData["HP", "2018"], "Month"];

Column[Data2018AgM]
```

Yields the values for Jan1-Feb1, Feb2-Mar1, Mar2-Apr1 and so on.

```
{{1, "Month"}, {-1, "Day"}}
```

Yields the values for Jan1-Jan31, Feb1-Feb27, Feb28-Mar27 and so on.

```
“EndOfMonth”
```

Yields the values for Jan1-Jan30, Jan31-Feb27, Feb28-Mar30 and so on.

I need to make the data fit exactly with the Jan1-Jan31, Feb1-Feb28, Mar1-Mar31, Apr1-Apr30 (...) windows but haven't been able to. There must be a simple elegant way of doing it that I'm missing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented with several different window specifications but was unable to get `TimeSeriesAggregate` to average over entire months. At first I thought this might be because `FinancialData` returned dates in the form `{YYYY, MM, DD}` rather than `DateObject` so I tried this

```
data = {DateObject[First[#]], Last[#]} & /@ FinancialData["HP", "2018"];
TimeSeriesAggregate[data, "Month"]
```

But it was still incorrect. Seems like a bug in `TimeSeriesAggregate`.

Here is a way to compute the mean by month

```
byMonth = GroupBy[data, DateValue[First[#], "MonthName"] &, #[[All, 2]] &];
meanByMonth = Mean[#] & /@ byMonth
```

Evaluates to

```
<|"January" -> 70.09, "February" -> 66.39, "March" -> 65.7829, "April" -> 70.189, "May" -> 69.5391, "June" -> 64.3086,   "July" ->
62.4019, "August" -> 63.3765, "September" -> 65.9926, "October" -> 70.4233|>
```